# Is it possible to speed up move_to_element() in Selenium or what are other alternatives?

Tags: javascript, selenium, scrapy, action, onmouseover

What is the fastest way to trigger an onmouseover event when scraping a webpage?

So I want to move the mouse over a div element, which is then calling a javascript function to update another div (displaying a tooltip, which I want to scrape). When moving the mouse off the first div, the tooltip disappears, but it can still be scraped, because only the display style is set to none. 
I would like to make this procedure as quick as possible.

Currently I use Selenium and move_to_element which takes roughly 0.55s. This is quite long, as I have to repeat this procedure eventually >60 times.

```
start_time = time.time()
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(box)
action.perform()
print("Time: ", time.time() - start_time()) # ~0.5s
```

When I use this in the scrapy shell, I see the following message displayed for this selenium request.

```
[selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:57309/session/49aea696ad5c6a23dd1a292adacf1d92/actions {"actions": [{"parameters": {"pointerType": "mouse"}, "type": "pointer", "id": "mouse", "actions": [{"duration": 250, "x": 0, "type": "pointerMove", "y": 0, "origin": {"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf": "63f7afad-d9d6-49c2-989a-75c6d083c055"}}]}, {"type": "key", "id": "key", "actions": [{"duration": 0, "type": "pause"}]}]}
```

At "actions" it says "duration: 250", I suspect this is the duration time of the move_to_element action. I wasn't able to find any way to manually reduce this duration, is this possible?
I also heard that scrapy-splash is way quicker than selenium, but haven't found alot on how to use it. Can it also emulate hover events, or call the javascript function directly with the correct arguments?

Comment: Even if you did it 100 times, you're still talking less than a minute. What's the problem? It sounds like you have more than one true test in a single script. Instead, break the test into smaller, individual tests and run them in parallel. That way you test the same scenarios but it gets done faster.

Comment: That is true, however I use this for scraping (I know Selenium was not designed for that in the first place), this means I run this 100 times on a single page but then again hundreds of times for different pages. So a runtime of 30-50s adds up to running the scraper several hours, eventually days (already parallelized). So if it was possible to half the duration on a single page, that already has significant impact on the overall time.

Comment: You could alternative consider not using Selenium in the first place, it’s usually not necessary for web scraping: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1):

Although this is old.  If it helps anyone... at least in Python selenium module you can set the duration of the mouse movement by setting the following property on the action chain:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
act = ActionChains(driver)
act.w3c_actions.pointer_action._duration = 0
```

The default value appears to be set to 250.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of things:

- [onmouseover](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp): `onmouseover` event executes a JavaScript when moving the mouse pointer onto an image. An example:

  ```
  <img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley">
  ```
- [move_to_element(to_element)](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element): `move_to_element()` moves the mouse to the middle of an element.
- The time which you have measured i.e. *~0.55s* involves a couple of other activities along with `move_to_element(to_element)` such as:

  - `action = ActionChains(driver)`
  - `action.perform()`
  - `print()` etc.

Now it is worth to mention that, methods of [action_chains](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) by default ensures that that the desired element is [is_displayed()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_displayed) and [is_enabled()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_enabled) within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

---

### Conclusion

Considering the above mentioned facts, `~500-550 ms` of timespan looks pretty optimized.

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, after I upgrade my Chrome version the actions fires substantially slower, now it hits around 0.5'ish seconds, but before it was well below 0.1 second (used to have chrome 60 something)